# AreaActionLink Extension Method and namespace bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I wanted to add an extension method to the `HtmlHelper` class so that developers could generically retrieve and `AreaActionLink<T>` without having to add the `new { area = "MyArea" }` each time as well as not have to specify a `Controller`. This all works well and good if I specify the namespace or put the namespace of the Area Controller in the Web.config.

For instance if I change the Area controller namespace to `My.Web.Controllers` rather than `My.Web.MyArea.Controllers` it throws a 404 but if I use the namespace it resolves properly.

```
public static MvcHtmlString AreaActionLink<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes) where T : IController
{
    RouteValueDictionary routes = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);
    string area = typeof(T).GetArea();
    if (!routes.ContainsKey("area"))
        routes.Add("area", area);

    return helper.ActionLink(linkText, 
        actionName, 
        typeof(T).Name.Replace("Controller", string.Empty), 
        routes, 
        htmlAttributes as Dictionary<string, object>);
}
```

This works if the namespace is fully qualified when calling AreaActionLink

```
namespace My.Web.Areas.MyArea.Controllers
{
    [Area("MyArea")]
    public class OtherPlaceController : Controller
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

and called like this:

```
<%=Html.AreaActionLink<OtherPlaceController>("Link Text", "MyAction")%>
```

but if I try to flatten the namespace hierarchy so I don't have to add a new namespace for ever Area it throws a 404.

```
namespace My.Web.Controllers
{
    [Area("MyArea")]
    public class OtherPlaceController : Controller
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

It seems that the `.Areas` portion of the namespace is important but I can't figure out why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm sure you've become accustomed to, by default ASP.NET MVC is *very* much dependent on directory structure (controllers need to be in "Controllers" folder, views in "Views", etc.)  This is just more of the same.  Your areas *should* be in separate folders -- that's actually one of the main reasons to have them! :)

Comment: Yes, my areas are in sub folders from the root but I was trying to get flat namespaces so that I didn't have to fully qualify the namespace when calling my extension method or have to add each new Area to the web.config. I guess it's a one time thing so it's not *too* bad.